# Python for文の中で，複数の変数を宣言？したい

Tags: python, python3

よろしくお願いします。

現在，for文の中で`pd.read_csv`を回して複数のcsvを読み込もうとしています

しかし，どのようにfor文の中で（連番の）変数を作れば良いのかがわかりません。
例えば，おかしなコードになってしまいますが

```
for i in range(5):
    name(i) =pd.read_csv(～)
```

のような感じで，name0 ~ name4というDataframeを作成したいです

よろしくお願いします

Comment: そのfor文は何を基準に繰り返しをしているのでしょうか? そのあたりのコードも示すと的確な回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。むちゃくちゃな例に成ってしまっていますが，編集しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リストでいかがでしょうか?

```
name = []
for i in range(5):
    name.append(pd.read_csv(～))
```

という感じです。

ただし、`name0`〜`name4` でなく、`name[0]`〜`name[4]` となりますが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。無事やりたかった処理を行えました。