# Google colabのループ内で変数名に連番をつける方法はありますか？

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

行列を使わずに連番のついた変数にデータを代入することは可能でしょうか

たとえば、

```py
while n <= 10: 
    n=+1
```

でループさせたとして、`text`という変数に`n`を加えて、`n`のデータを代入するような

```py
text1 = 1
text2 = 2
text3 = 3
```

と処理することはできますか？

---

コメントでアドバイス頂いて解決しました。
execを使えば行けるようです。
ありがとうございました。

command = 'test' + str(n) + '= n'
exec(command)

Comment: この辺の記事と重複しているかもしれませんね。[Pythonで連番のオブジェクトを宣言する際の良い書き方について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59579/26370), [連番の変数を作成するときの繰り返しをどうすればよろしいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54183/26370), [Python for文の中で，複数の変数を宣言？したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/43984/26370), [execで連番の変数名を動的に生成するのに代る方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36330/26370), [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/9014308)

Comment: 「行列を使わずに」ですが, 理由の説明(根拠？)など 質問に添えられてると答えやすいかも。普通に考えれば `dict`や `array`などがオススメで, 理由もなく面倒そうな手法を回答で出すのは憚られるかも

Comment: 理由を書いたほうがいいとアドバイスを受けたため追記します。
別の処理でデータセットを読み込んでおり、それに連番がついています。aa01, aa02・・・みたいなデータです。
そのファイルを別のデータを順々に代入（置き換え）していきたいのですが、データセットの数が不明なため、データの総数をカウントして、その数だけループして、データを代入していきたいと考えています。
aa01にbb01を代入、aa02にbb02を・・・

ですので、ループの中で、連番のついたファイル名を指定できる方法を知りたいと思っております。
始めたばかりのコピペプログラマーで基礎を知らないので、意味の分かってないところがあるかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どうやら[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)のようですね。それから「行列」が数学的な意味を持つデータなのか、単なる「配列」や「リスト」の言い換えなのかでも変わってくるでしょう。前提条件・やりたい/やらなければならない事とか、基となるディレクトリ/ファイル構成・ファイル内のデータ構造、結果として欲しい内容などを細かい手順に分解していけば、たいていのことは配列/リスト/辞書などで処理できるでしょう。pandasとかが使えるかもしれませんし。なお、追加の説明はコメントにするのではなく、質問記事自身を編集して分かりやすいように追記してください。

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に追記してしまうのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。(質問はあくまで "質問" の体裁を保ってください)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

常識的には以下でいいです。

```py
texts = list(range(1, 11))
```

どうしてもtext1のような名前の変数がほしいならlocals()やglobals()を使う方法があります。

```py
for i in range(1, 11):
    locals()[f"text{i}"] = i
```

ご自身が質問に追記しているように、execでもいいです。

```py
for i in range(1, 11):
    exec(f"text{i}={i}")
```